# Shuffeling strings so no object is in it's original place

Tags: java, shuffle

Is there a way to shuffle an array of string in a way that no string is in it's original position? Rotation is not an option

Comment: How could you do that if there is only a single String?

Comment: If you move the first string to the end, none of them are in their original position.  Would that do?

Comment: What if there are two elements in the array "Hilda", and the two get switched? The two objects have been switched but the values are the same. Is that acceptable?

Comment: No, I want it to be random. The solution has to be different each time and not predictable and rotating is not an option.

Comment: Do you want every string to *always* be in a different position, or just random? There's a difference.

Comment: Not necessarily. They don't always have to be in different positions.

Comment: This is called a "derangement".  You could try searching for "derangement algorithm".

Comment: See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/218255/shuffling-algorithm-with-no-self-mapping

Answer (score 4):

You could implement a [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle), but on each iteration exclude the current position from the random range. This is actually [a common mistake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors) that reduces the quality of the shuffle.

EDIT: Reading on, I see that this actually has a name: [Sattolo's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle#Sattolo.27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

This is just one method. I'm sure there are faster or more efficient methods, but this works just fine.

```
static Random r;
public static String[] shuffle(String[] input)
{
    if(r == null) r = new Random();

    String[] output = new String[input.length];
    ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) indices.add(i);

    for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
    {
        int randomIndicesIndex = r.nextInt(indices.size());
        int randomIndex = indices.get(randomIndicesIndex);
        indices.remove(randomIndicesIndex);
        output[i] = input[randomIndex];
    }

    return output;
}
```

When called in a loop, it outputs this result:

```
01: Hilda, Quinn, Lyon, Danny, Rob, Clyde, Joe, Jeff, Samantha
02: Hilda, Samantha, Clyde, Danny, Lyon, Joe, Quinn, Rob, Jeff
03: Rob, Samantha, Hilda, Joe, Danny, Jeff, Lyon, Clyde, Quinn
04: Jeff, Lyon, Joe, Quinn, Clyde, Hilda, Rob, Danny, Samantha
05: Danny, Jeff, Hilda, Lyon, Joe, Samantha, Rob, Clyde, Quinn
06: Lyon, Danny, Jeff, Quinn, Rob, Hilda, Clyde, Samantha, Joe
07: Clyde, Hilda, Rob, Samantha, Lyon, Quinn, Danny, Jeff, Joe
08: Clyde, Jeff, Samantha, Danny, Quinn, Hilda, Joe, Lyon, Rob
09: Jeff, Samantha, Danny, Clyde, Rob, Joe, Quinn, Lyon, Hilda
10: Clyde, Samantha, Danny, Lyon, Rob, Hilda, Quinn, Jeff, Joe
```

Comment: Is this using a certain famous algorithm?

Comment: @user3000837 Maybe! I have no idea though. I'm sure someone has used it before, but it's just how I would solve the problem. It uses slightly more memory (the indices array) to improve the speed.

Comment: That does not solve the problem. I still some assignments that are in the same place. @TheAdamGaskins

Comment: @user3000837 You said: `No, I want it to be random.` And `Not necessarily. They don't always have to be in different positions.` This snippet fulfills these requirements.